# Automatically Adjust height and Vertically Center A Centered Div within a container

Tags: html, css

I have div container that is centered in the middle of a container. I was able to adjust it to one slide however, the problem I encountered is I have made several .html files using the same css file and the height of the is not what I expected. I was hoping that height of the container will wrap around the content automatically regardless of height size but not ignoring the margins, padding etc given to the content container.

Below are my codes and an image of the output that I have right now.

```css
.template-benefits{
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
.tbenefitswrpr {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 50px 0 0 0 ;
}
.template-benefits h3{
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
.template-benefits ul li{
 list-style-type: disc;
}

.tbenefitswrpr h1{
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.tbenefitswrpr ul{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.tbenefitswrpr li{
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="template-benefits">
 <div class="tbenefitswrpr">
 <div class="tbenefits-left">
  <h1>Preventative maintenance of equipment and assets</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Schedule recurring work orders for routine preventative maintenance for anything from computers, technology, and other appliances or equipment</li>
   <li>Easily view schedule of past completed maintenance work orders</li>
   <li>Custom dashboards to track preventative maintenance</li>
  </ul>
 </div> 
 <div class="tbenefits-right">
  <h1>Building and facility management</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Manage multiple facilities all in one organized place</li>
   <li>Easily view past completed security and safety inspections</li>
   <li>Assign and coordinate work orders for repairs for utilities, plumbing, and broken appliances</li>
  </ul>
 </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmV2V.png)

Comment: tbenefits-left and tbenefits-right should have width: 50% ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `.tbenefits-left{float: left;width: 50%;margin-right: 20px;}`

Comment: add some more details

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```css
.template-benefits{
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
.tbenefitswrpr {
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 height: 400px;
 padding: 50px 0 0 0 ;
}
.template-benefits h3{
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: rgb(150,150,150);
}
.template-benefits ul li{
 list-style-type: disc;
}

.tbenefitswrpr h1{
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.tbenefitswrpr ul{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.tbenefitswrpr li{
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

/*---update---*/
.tbenefits-left{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="template-benefits">
 <div class="tbenefitswrpr">
 <div class="tbenefits-left">
  <h1>Preventative maintenance of equipment and assets</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Schedule recurring work orders for routine preventative maintenance for anything from computers, technology, and other appliances or equipment</li>
   <li>Easily view schedule of past completed maintenance work orders</li>
   <li>Custom dashboards to track preventative maintenance</li>
  </ul>
 </div> 
 <div class="tbenefits-right">
  <h1>Building and facility management</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Manage multiple facilities all in one organized place</li>
   <li>Easily view past completed security and safety inspections</li>
   <li>Assign and coordinate work orders for repairs for utilities, plumbing, and broken appliances</li>
  </ul>
 </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```